# Issue with multiple JOINs in ODBC connection

Tags: sql, join, odbc, netsuite

I am connecting to a NetSuite database via ODBC and created a rather large query for the database to run a report. I've placed the code at the end of this post. My problem is, the query is excluding rows from the "A_T_PROJECTS" table that have NULL in the "TRADING_PARTNER_ID" field. I know I could use a RIGHT OUTER JOIN here, but I can't seem to get it to work due to the fact that I am joining several other tables. Any suggestions on what I can try?

The connection is read-only, so no temporary tables - and I'd like this to work in a single query. Thanks for your time!

```
SELECT
    [A_T_CUSTOMERS].[COMPANYNAME] AS [Company Name],
    [A_T_MILESTONES].[PROJECT_MILESTONE_NAME] AS [Name],
    [A_T_PROJECTS].[COMPANYNAME] AS [Project Name],
    [A_T_STATUS].[LIST_ITEM_NAME] AS [Status],
    [A_T_MILESTONES].[DUE_DATE] AS [Milestone Due],
    [A_T_ACTIONREQ].[LIST_ITEM_NAME] AS [Action Required By],
    [A_T_PARTNERS].[COMPANYNAME] AS [Trading Partner],
    [A_T_EMPLOYEES].[FULL_NAME] AS [Assigned To],
    [A_T_CUSTOMERS].[ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE] AS [Est Del Date],
    CASE
            WHEN [A_T_MILESTONES].[PROJECT_MILESTONE_NAME] = 'Project Complete/Move to Production'
                    THEN [A_T_MILESTONES].[DUE_DATE]
            ELSE NULL
    END AS [Est Move to Prod]

FROM
    [CUSTOMERS] AS [A_T_CUSTOMERS],
    [CUSTOMERS] AS [A_T_PROJECTS],
    [PROJECT_MILESTONE] AS [A_T_MILESTONES],
    [PARTNERS] AS [A_T_PARTNERS],
    [STATUS] AS [A_T_STATUS],
    [ACTION_REQUIRED] AS [A_T_ACTIONREQ],
    [EMPLOYEES] AS [A_T_EMPLOYEES]
    --RIGHT OUTER JOIN [PARTNERS] ON ([A_T_PARTNERS].[PARTNER_ID] = [A_T_PROJECTS].[TRADING_PARTNER_ID])

WHERE
    -- JOIN CLAUSES --
    [A_T_PROJECTS].[CUSTOMER_ID] = [A_T_MILESTONES].[PROJECT_NAME_ID]
    AND [A_T_CUSTOMERS].[CUSTOMER_ID] = [A_T_MILESTONES].[CUSTOMER_MILESTONE_NAME_ID]
    AND [A_T_PARTNERS].[PARTNER_ID] = [A_T_PROJECTS].[TRADING_PARTNER_ID]
    AND [A_T_EMPLOYEES].[EMPLOYEE_ID] = [A_T_MILESTONES].[ASSIGNED_TO_ID]
    AND [A_T_STATUS].[LIST_ID] = [A_T_MILESTONES].[STATUS_ID]
    AND [A_T_ACTIONREQ].[LIST_ID] = [A_T_MILESTONES].[ACTION_REQUIRED_BY_ID]

    -- FILTER CLAUSES --
    AND [A_T_CUSTOMERS].[CUSTOMER_SINCE] > '2011-12-10 00:00:00'
    AND ([A_T_MILESTONES].[STATUS_ID] = 1
            OR [A_T_MILESTONES].[STATUS_ID] = 2
            OR [A_T_MILESTONES].[STATUS_ID] = 3
            OR [A_T_MILESTONES].[STATUS_ID] = 5)
    AND ([A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'Assigned'
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'Delayed - per Customer'
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'Delayed - per Internal'
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'Delayed - per TP/VAN'
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'In Progress'
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'Production'
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[STATUS] = 'On-Hold')
    AND [A_T_CUSTOMERS].[TRANSLATOR_ID] != 4
    AND [A_T_CUSTOMERS].[IN_PRODUCTION] = 'F'
    AND ([A_T_PROJECTS].[JOB_TYPE_ID] IS NOT NULL
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[JOB_TYPE_ID] != 8
            OR [A_T_PROJECTS].[JOB_TYPE_ID] != 11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `JOIN` for each table instead of using WHERE clauses to link them.  If both tables need to contain the same "Id", then use `TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id=TableB.Id`.  If you want all the TableA records even if some are missing in TableB, use the `TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id=TableB.Id`.  Any field from TableB without a match will show up as `NULL`.

You can nest all the `JOIN` claues.  I'm not sure how **netsuite** handles things, but you may need to put `()` around the join clauses.

```
FROM (TableA AS A INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.id=B.id)
                  LEFT JOIN TableC AS C ON A.id=C.id
```

Good luck.

Comment: I didn't know I could group JOINs like that. Learn something new every day! I'll give it a shot. Thank you!